# What's the way of reading where words appear on the screen every time period?

Tags: text, terminology, readability

I think I've heard of a way of reading in which words appear on the screen every second or less. For example, I've seen it used in some dynamic Apple promo and it works. What's the method of reading called?

Comment: There's no question here to be answered.

Comment: Well, apparently the guy who answered it is an astrophysicist.

Comment: This has nothing to do with graphic design.

Comment: @bad_mouse9199 There was no question to be asked in your original post. I edited it to match the Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is called [Rapid Serial Visual Presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_serial_visual_presentation). There are various tools that use this, like [SwiftRead](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swiftread-read-faster-lea/ipikiaejjblmdopojhpejjmbedhlibno) and [Sprint Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sprint-reader-speed-readi/kejhpkmainjkpiablnfdppneidnkhdif/).